# .net 6 web api request change float model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, webapi

I send request from web:
[image]

in model:

```
public float Team { get; set; }
```

But i got incorrect value:

[image]

What is problem with rounded ?
How fix it in webapi?

I have many method , fields , levels i dont want resolve by hand every fields by Math.Round or other functions ....

update 1. for @MdFaridUddinKiron

```
public IActionResult Save([FromBody] Model req){
     return Ok();
}

public class Model {
   public float Team { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Maytham i know about it. Question how its fix in asp.net web api. In NodeJs we havent it problem

Comment: in asp.net is there no single approach to the web api solution? I wrote in question "have many method , fields , levels i dont want resolve by hand EVERY fields by Math.Round or other functions"

Comment: Did you able to resolved the issue?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron no :(  waiting for experts

Comment: Could you please share your full controller along with the model.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron added

Comment: How are you sending the request? I have just reproduced your issue and I am getting `0.91` as expected. No issue I have founded. Would you kindly check your code? How the the value being sent from your `client side app` I think problem is there not in API. In cases where you are using  *.js* kind of language, double check that the value is being passed as expected, since *javascript* often adds extra precision.

Answer (score 1):

try using a `double` instead.

[floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), by how they are rapresented, are not good for precision unless we are talking about extremely small numbers.

Here is a nice little article explaining why floats may lose precision (its for cpp, but the general concept should be the same for c#):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/why-floating-point-numbers-may-lose-precision?view=msvc-170

Edit:
I found this 13 years old question in the suggested section that might definitivelty help you understand more about floats and doubles:
[Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/17350905)